# How can I control game servers via webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for the broad question I have no where else to go for information, I have googled the hell out of this. I use Node and for a little side project I wanted to make a webpage for my friends clan on counter-strike I wanted to have the ability to stop or restart the server via the webpage. I'm just unsure what to use to monitor the server, and to trigger a restart / shutdown / start. Could you guys please just tell me what to google for that sense? Will I need to create a backend that monitors the service, and reports to the webpage? I have googled many different things but as I stated before, no luck. Thanks for absolutely any information you guys can offer.

Like I said, sorry for such a broad not very well explained question, but this is my last place to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably already stumbled on to [**this**](http://albulescu.com/using-nodejs-to-read-counter-strike-server-info) during your google searches. Describes using NodeJs to communicate with Counterstrike servers. And you probably already found [**this**](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries) as well, describing the possible things you can query the server for (realtime) for the server/games in-progress, etc.

To querying the server from your web page, you would integrate those calls into the page/site.

As for starting/restarting/shutting down the server via the webpage:

1. really bad idea to make this available in a web page. Major security
   issue.
2. I didnt read through the entire Valve SDK but if remote admin access
   to servers is available, it'll be documented in there how to go
   about it.

If you are meaning a private game server you guys run, it would depend on if it is hosted on one of your computers or on a server one of you have admin access to. If the SDK doesn't support starting/restarting, etc via requests, you could make workarounds but it may be more work than it's worth. TCP/IP connections with the proper headers to rented host server sent from your website could do it. If its hosted on a home PC, same deal but opening a bit of a security vulnerability to your PC this route. Or, if both the server and the website are hosted on your machine, you can use named pipes to communicate with the server instance or shell commands fired by an authenticated remote request. It would be a bit of a pain in the *ss to do remote access from your website on your own either way.

Hope this helps a bit. if you send me a bit more detail about how the game and the site are hosted and I'll probably be able to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll mark this for answer unless anything more helpful comes up, but great answer. No for the life of me I never found either of those links, but they look incredibly useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it:

1. Have a webserver running in server.
2. Have web service running in server on top of webserver.
3. Webserver would serve the page(say control_page) which would help you to control game server.
4. From control_page call the webservice on some user action. Sending the action detail via webservice.
5. Based on the action send via webservice, web service should take the action( control action on game server) and report back to the user as return value to webservice.